# Using an XNA (Windows) Game Library with a XNA (Windows) Game Project

Tags: c#, dll, xna, libraries

I've been trying to create a reusable library to use across multiple games, so I created a Windows Game Library with my reusable classes, however I can't seem to figure out how to use the library in my game project. I've tried adding a reference to the `.dll` file to my game project references and also tried adding the project to my game solution (I was just screwing around trying to get it to work), but I'm not even entirely sure that the Windows Game Library is the project type I should be using.

In short: Is the Windows Game Library the appropriate project type to create a reusable, multi-game library? And, How do you use the classes within that library in an XNA Windows Game project?

Comment: Note: In the future, if you're truly only using reusable code, you can always make a Portable Class Library. This can run almost anywhere you want it to, due to its basic nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your on the right track, you need to have them in the same project, and have the game reference the project (not .dll) directly. To do this, go to your main game, select `Add Reference`.

When the dialog pops up, find `Solution`, and under it `Projects`. You should see your library in there, tick the checkbox and it will be referenced.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/U88z0SJ.png]

As far as the solution layout goes, and how to use the library in your game, I created a quick illustration:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/VHQM0Oc.png]

Comment: Thanks you so much! I had trouble for a minute because the dialog in VS2010 express looks a bit different, but I have it working now. I added the library project to my game solution before adding the reference. Thanks again!